# useState does not update state immediately, it does updated in web page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

```
export default function Test() {
const [steps, setSteps] = useState(0);

function increment() {
setSteps(steps=>steps+2);
console.log(steps)
  if(steps==2)//doesnot go in if
  {

  }
}

return (
<div>
  Today you've taken {steps} steps!
  <br />
  <button onClick={increment}>
    step
  </button>
</div>
);
}
```

after updating state i am not getting updated value in console and doesnot go in if statement as well. what am i doing wrong its being correctly shown in web page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately

Comment: `setSteps(steps=>steps+2)` change to `setSteps(steps + 2)` and it should work.

Comment: no, same issue again

Comment: @jk123 is the same issue.... Just setState is async method so it will be executed in nearly future of component life cycle. If you need react on steps change you have to use useEffect and in dependency array pass steps state, then in this function you can check if is equal 2.